# Trying to install wine32 i386 packages on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I've been break my back over trying to fix this issue with Wine32 as I am trying to make it work on my Ubuntu 18.04 Laptop.

First I added i386 architecture using

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

And checked it with

```
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

and confirming that i386 does indeed exist there.
Moving on to running

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

I simply get

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Breaks: aptitude:i386 (< 0.8.10)
 aptitude:i386 : Depends: libapt-pkg4.12:i386 (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-iostreams1.46.1:i386 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcwidget3:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libept1.4.12:i386 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libncursesw5:i386 (>= 5.6+20070908) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxapian22:i386 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: apt-xapian-index:i386 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 aptitude-common : Recommends: aptitude
                   Breaks: aptitude:i386 (< 0.8.10-4)
 ppa-purge : Depends: aptitude
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: wine-stable:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I tried doing the same with Aptitude but without any luck, when I'm running commands with Aptitude I'm running into errors like

```
aptitude: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so I moved back to apt-get and am trying to fix the broken packages and am getting the following output

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcwidget3v5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aptitude:i386 libapt-pkg5.0:i386 libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386
  libboost-iostreams1.65.1:i386 libboost-system1.65.1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libcwidget3v5:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libxapian30:i386
  libzstd1:i386
Suggested packages:
  aptitude-doc-en:i386 | aptitude-doc:i386 apt-xapian-index:i386 debtags:i386
  tasksel:i386 libcwidget-dev:i386 xapian-tools:i386
Recommended packages:
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 apt:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apt-utils ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  update-manager update-notifier update-notifier-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapt-pkg5.0:i386 libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386
  libboost-iostreams1.65.1:i386 libboost-system1.65.1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libcwidget3v5:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libxapian30:i386
  libzstd1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aptitude:i386
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt
1 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 8 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4.565 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2.320 kB of additional disk space will be used.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

Last time I did this it messed up ubuntu and required me install packages so I could actually access the desktop, it just droppe me into and startup error screen with only a command line.
How the hell am I supposed to fix that? I've been going pretty hard at it, trying to install individual dependencies but I am running into more trouble such as installing 1 dependency which asks to remove 20 other packages that I need to use for ubuntu to function.

Fresh installation doesn't help and I have tried Lutris/PlayOnLinux.
On PlayOnLinux I get

```
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
http://www.freetype.org
err:syslink:SYSLINK_SetFont Failed to create link font!
```

I am really lost and have tried ANY solution I could find online but none seem to work, if there's any way to solve it without breaking my ubuntu installation and doing a fresh install, I'll apreciate it alot

Comment: There's no i386 (32-bit) architecture for standard Ubuntu 18.04 and that's why you're seeing those errors.

Comment: Any work around or fix?

Comment: Remove the foreign (and inexistent) architecture for starters.

Comment: I'm trying <code>sudo apt-get purge "*.*:i386"</code>
but I get <code>You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ppa-purge : Depends: aptitude
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
</code>